# Trying to set an html attribute to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable "count" in javascript and a radio button that I want to depend on that variable. There is a button to generate more radio buttons, which is why I need their name attributes to differ.

My code:

```
var count = 1;
function newForm(){
...<input name=count type="radio" value="Website" />...
}
```

But it's just setting the name of each additional radio button to "count" rather than the number "count" represents.

Here's the whole code:

```
var count = 1;
function newForm(){
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="line"></div><br><input type="text" name="Name" 
class="field" placeholder="Full Event Name" /><br><input type="text" name="Location"       
placeholder="Event Location" class="field" /><br> <input type="text" name="Date" 
placeholder="Event Date" class="field" /> <br> <input type="text" name="End" 
placeholder="Event End Date (If Applicable)" class="field" /> <br> <input type="text" 
name="Time" placeholder="Event Time" class="field" /> <br> <input type="text"     
name="Tags" 
placeholder="Relevant Tags" class="field" /> <br> The info is from: <input name=count 
type="radio" value="Tweet" checked="" />Tweet <input name=count type="radio"   
value="Website" 
/>Website <input name=count type="radio" value="Tweet and Website" /> Tweet and  
Website';
if(count < 10) {
    document.getElementById('formSpace').appendChild(newdiv);
    count++;
}
```

}

That newdiv.innerHTML string above is all on one line in the code, by the way.

Comment: Why don't you post the entire code so we can see what you're doing with that string, and show you how to concatenate the variable into the string.

Comment: more code please. you probably have something wrong with the way you are creating the radio button. a missing quote or double quote or something.

Comment: Please share the whole JS. You're passing count as a string and not as a variable. It should looks something like this: `'<input name="radio' + count + '" type="radio" value="Websaite" />';`

Comment: Oh God, don't create large pieces of markup with strings like that !

Comment: Why don't you accept any of those answers? They both seem to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to create an element, use `createElement()` :

```
var count = 1;

function newForm(){
     var input = document.createElement('input');

     input.name  = count;
     input.type  = 'radio';
     input.value = 'Website';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your long string of innerHTML you need to escape your "count" variable... otherwise it's just a string... i.e.

```
'<input name='+count+' type="radio" value="Tweet and Website" />';
```

That will make it work but as everyone else is mentioning - you really shouldn't embed long html strings like this.